# Avoid adding duplicates to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I would to store the distance between 4 clusters, so I took the sum of the distance between cluster x and cluster y and vise versa -since the distance between cluster x and cluster y != cluster y and cluster x- then divide them by 2 so it would be non directional.

The problem I'm facing here is the duplication. How can I end up with only 6 distances and avoid adding duplicates to the array in the first place.

Notes:

- I made DistanceBetweenClusterToAnother a two dimensional array with the goal of solving this issue, since I couldn't solve it with one dimensional array.
- this.clusterSize() equals 4.

  ```
  for (int k = 0; k < this.clusterSize(); k++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < this.clusterSize(); j++) {
          if (k != j) {
              DistanceBetweenClusterToAnother[k][j] = GADOfCluster1toCluster2[k][j] + GADOfCluster1toCluster2[j][k];
              DistanceBetweenClusterToAnother[k][j]= DistanceBetweenClusterToAnother[k][j]/2;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I can't even wrap my mind around how the distance between x and y is not equal to the distance between y and x...

Comment: @AlvinThompson if the distance function is not symmetric, like in a directed graph for instance :)

Comment: Why not just start the inner loop at `j = k + 1`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you so much, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would be the optimal way, but you can check the array for an match.

```
if (valueYouWantToCheck == Array.getIndex(i))
    Array.add(valueYouWantToCheck);
```

Comment: Of course add this within a for so you can i++ at the Index to scan the whole Array. (This is my first time answering something here so I'm sorry for bad formatting)

Comment: Your code will add the element to the array if it finds it is already in the array. Are you sure this is what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Start the inner loop after the current position of the outer loop. Also, you can average in one line:

```
for (int k = 0; k < this.clusterSize(); k++) {
    for (int j = k + 1; j < this.clusterSize(); j++) {
        DistanceBetweenClusterToAnother[k][j] = (GADOfCluster1toCluster2[k][j] + GADOfCluster1toCluster2[j][k]) / 2;
    }
}
```